# How to duplicate the shipments grid in another custom url from the admin panel?

Tags: magento2, grid, uicomponent

my goal is duplicate the default shipments grid in another page from the admin panel.

So far I've created my layout xml:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="styles"/>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <uiComponent name="vendor_modulename_shipments_grid"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

and in the `ui_component/vendor_modulename_shipments_grid.xml`, I've added this:

```
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">vendor_modulename_shipments_grid.vendor_modulename_listing_data_source</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <settings>
        <buttons>
            <button name="add">
                <url path="*/*/new"/>
                <class>primary</class>
                <label translate="true">My new button</label>
            </button>
        </buttons>
        <spinner>shipments_columns</spinner>
        <deps>
            <dep>vendor_modulename_shipments_grid.vendor_modulename_listing_data_source</dep>
        </deps>
    </settings>
    <dataSource name="vendor_modulename_listing_data_source" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider">
        <settings>
            <updateUrl path="mui/index/render"/>
        </settings>
        <dataProvider class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider" name="vendor_modulename_listing_data_source">
            <settings>
                <requestFieldName>id</requestFieldName>
                <primaryFieldName>entity_id</primaryFieldName>
            </settings>
        </dataProvider>
    </dataSource>
    <columns name="my_column_name">
        <column name="order_increment_id">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                 <label translate="true">Order #</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

I've didn't want to copy all of the columns from the core file: `vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_shipment_grid.xml` , so I've added only one : `order_increment_id`.

So far I am getting this message : `Not registered handle vendor_modulename_listing_data_source`. Please advice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must define which collection is should be used for your data provider in the `di.xml`, like this:

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="vendor_modulename_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Model\Model\ResourceModel\ModelName\Collection</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
 </type>
```

Because in the collection factory that exception throws in case there no collection related to `vendor_modulename_listing_data_source` (the `$name` argument) .

Here is code of the collection factory with that exception:

> vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponent/DataProvider/CollectionFactory.php

```
/**
 * Class CollectionPool
 */
class CollectionFactory
{
    /**
     * @var Collection[]
     */
    protected $collections;

    /**
     * @var ObjectManagerInterface
     */
    protected $objectManager;

    /**
     * @param ObjectManagerInterface $objectManagerInterface
     * @param array $collections
     */
    public function __construct(
        ObjectManagerInterface $objectManagerInterface,
        array $collections = []
    ) {
        $this->collections = $collections;
        $this->objectManager = $objectManagerInterface;
    }

    /**
     * Get report collection
     *
     * @param string $requestName
     * @return Collection
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function getReport($requestName)
    {
        if (!isset($this->collections[$requestName])) {
            throw new \Exception(sprintf('Not registered handle %s', $requestName));
        }
        $collection = $this->objectManager->create($this->collections[$requestName]);
        if (!$collection instanceof Collection) {
            throw new \Exception(sprintf('%s is not of Collection type.', $requestName));
        }
        return $collection;
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool, Thnx for the quick answer, it works. One more question, if i would like to filter that grid after lets say the order status for the shipment grid. where should I add that filter and how ?

Comment: @AttilaNaghi If I understand you right, you must add a custom filter inside your own collection. If you want to add a column with filter to existing collection (listing) here is [my post](https://www.mageworx.com/blog/how-to-add-column-with-filter-to-magento-2-orders-grid/) with example code (but for orders listing).

Comment: thx for helping me out. NO, I don't want another column, I want to filter the shipment collection after the order status . I saw the need to create another post here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/302026/how-to-add-where-clause-or-join-condition-to-the-shipment-grid-using-ui-componen. IF you any suggestions ,would be really nice :) thnx